# How to inject dependencies with post call in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a post mapping which will map to a profile.Profile contains certain parameters based on which I want to inject dependencies.
For every profile there can be completely different set of implementations that I want to inject.
With guice I was able to do that by adding module property to my profile and create that guice module when I was receiving the profile and other dependencies injection were take care by guice.

```
public class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
public GuiceModule(Profile profile) {
                    super(profile);
                  }
                @Override
                protected void configureModule() { 
                  bind(Bean1.class).toProvider(Bean1Impl.class);
                  bind(Bean2.class).to(Bean2Impl.class);
                  bind(Bean3.class).to(Bean3Impl.class);
                  bind(Bean4.class).to(Bean4Impl.class);
                  bind(Bean5.class).to(Bean5Imple.class);
                  bind(ParentBean.class).to(ParentBeanImpl.class);
              }

              @Override
              public void configure() {
                this.configureModule();
              }   
    }
```

In My Controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/profiles/add" , consumes = "application/json")
    void addProfile(@RequestBody Profile profile)
        {
            //with guice 
            Injector injector = Guice.getInjector(Class.forName(profile.getModule));
            injector.getInstance(ParentBean.class).execute();
        }
```

But with spring-boot could not find out how to achieve this.
**Update** can I create a new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext everytime I receive a new profile in my post call.Code will look something like this.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/profiles/add" , consumes = "application/json")
void addProfile(@RequestBody Profile profile)
{
    String clazz = profile.getConfigurationClass();
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Class.forName(clazz)); //This will create a new IoC container with its own beans.
    ParentBean bean = context.getBean(ParentBean.class)
    bean.execute()
}
```

This can work but I am not sure if this is a good practice.

Comment: Please provide a more specific example. What sorts of parameters, and what sorts of implementations? What is this method supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Added sample code and details.

Comment: The usual pattern here is to keep a map with the implementations and perform a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

In the question, it is not clear that which parameter is deciding the service call. Assuming it is some enum then you can keep a map with enum as a key and autowire of service as a value. Now on the basis of that parameter, you can call different implementation.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/profiles/add" , consumes = "application/json")
void addProfile(@RequestBody Profile profile)
{
 Object service =  this.map.get("your_field");
 service.yourMethod(profile);
}
```

Comment: profile object contains a field which will be used to determine what injection I want to use.Also their can be hierarchy of dependencies which needs to be injected which I was defining in single juice module.@Configuration can help but can I decide which configuration class to load based on profile submitted via post call.

Comment: you can maintain `map` of your field in profile as a key and value as service.